# Open ipython notebook on existing notebook server

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm seeking a way to open ipynb file on an existing notebook server.

There is a notebook server on my home directory started as follows:

```
/home/myname$ ipython notebook
```

And I have a notebook file `/home/myname/work_dir/test.ipynb`.
I need a script to open this file on the notebook:

```
cd work_dir
ipynb_open test.ipynb  # No such command!
```

I know that I can open this ipynb on a new notebook server by the following command:

```
ipython notebook test.ipynb
```

But this command stands a new server, and I have to kill this server by hands.

In this case, since I know the directory where the notebook is executed, I can open `test.ipynb` by directly specifying its relative path:

```
open http://localhost:8888/node/work_dir/test.ipynb
```

But I want to resolve this address automatically.

Reading documents, I found an option `--existing`, but following command does not work.

```
ipython notebook --exsiting test.ipynb
```

So my questions are:

- Is there a command corresponding to `ipynb_open` noted above?
- Is there a way to gather information about running notebook servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say hello to `nbopen`, which does exactly this!

https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen

Running notebook servers write JSON files to disk with their information; there's a Python function `notebook.notebookapp.list_running_servers()` that iterates over the running servers, and this is what nbopen uses.

Nbopen also includes desktop integration so you can double-click on a .ipynb file to open it. But you can install the `nbopen` command without the desktop integration if you prefer.