# Is there an easy way to run an ipynb against an already running kernel non-interactively?

Tags: docker, integration-testing, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for something like a `--kernel` option to [runipy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/runipy).

The purpose is to integration-test a docker container which is supposed to present an ipython notebook service. I'd like to check that an example notebook runs against that host and port.

As I think about it more, that probably means uploading the notebook in question to the docker container somehow, asking it to run the notebook, and checking that it did. Suggestions on making that not-obnoxious would be very welcome.

[nbopen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nbopen) seems [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689319/open-ipython-notebook-on-existing-notebook-server), but also doesn't seem to let me specify a host and port.

Comment: nbopen is specifically for interactive use. I don't think there's anything like that ready made, but have a look at the [ExecutePreprocessor code](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py) in nbconvert - that could be adapted to point to a kernel that's already running.